# Docusign integration with MVC 5 Web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, docusignapi

We are trying to integrate docusign (Embedded signing / Embedded docusign console yet to decide which one) with an existing MVC 5 web application. I was looking for a starting point and came across your question. I have looked at the API walkthrough(7,8,9) , but I want to know how to start off. For example we will need to direct the user to an application form for them to fill out and sign after they register on the site. Post signing I would like to redirect them back to the website.

Any pointers or examples would be much appreciated.

Thanks much, Sunny

Below is my code - which was working till last firday ( but from yesterday I getting this error - 
"406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.
The page you are looking for cannot be opened by your browser because it has
a file name extension that your browser does not accept."

```
    protected const string IntegratorKey = "XXX-XXX";
    protected const string Environment = "http://demo.docusign.net";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Example #1...
        Console.WriteLine("Testing Walkthrough #7...");

        // configure application's integrator key, webservice url, and rest api version
        RestSettings.Instance.IntegratorKey = IntegratorKey;
        RestSettings.Instance.DocuSignAddress = Environment;
        RestSettings.Instance.WebServiceUrl = Environment + "/restapi/v2";

        docusign test = new docusign();
        test.EmbeddedSigning();
        Console.ReadLine(); // pause to show console output
    }

    private void EmbeddedSigning()
    {
        //*****************************************************************
        // ENTER VALUES FOR FOLLOWING VARIABLES!
        //*****************************************************************
        string AccountEmail = "s@something.com";
        string AccountPassword = "*****";
        string EnvelopeId = "xxxxxxx";              
        string RecipientEmail = "s@someone.com";
        string RecipientName = "someone";
        //*****************************************************************

        // user credentials 
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Email = AccountEmail;
        account.Password = AccountPassword;

        // make the login call (retrieves your baseUrl and accountId)
        bool result = account.Login();
        if (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login API call failed for user {0}.\nError Code:  {1}\nMessage:  {2}", account.Email, account.RestError.errorCode, account.RestError.message);
            return;
        }

        // create envelope object and assign login info
        Envelope envelope = new Envelope();           
        envelope.Login = account;           
        // assign the envelope id that was passed in
        envelope.EnvelopeId = EnvelopeId;
        //add one signer (single recipient embedded signing currently supported in DocuSign .NET Client)
        envelope.Recipients = new Recipients()
        {
            signers = new Signer[]
            {
                new Signer()
                {
                    email = RecipientEmail,
                    name = RecipientName,
                    recipientId = "1",
                    clientUserId = "1"
                }
            }
        };            

        try
        {
            result = envelope.GetRecipientView("http://example.com/");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }           
        Console.WriteLine(envelope.SenderViewUrl);

        Console.ReadLine();

        if (!result)
        {
            if (envelope.RestError != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error code:  {0}\nMessage:  {1}", envelope.RestError.errorCode, envelope.RestError.message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error encountered retrieving signing token, please review your envelope and recipient data.");
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // open the recipient view (SenderViewUrl field is re-used for the recipient URL)
            Process.Start(envelope.SenderViewUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code what you try. If you didn't try till now please have look on google and try some thing then put Q here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Embedded Signing

Embedded Signing does exactly what you want with the `returnUrl` parameter. This also allows the signer to sign without signing up for a DocuSign account, to streamline the process a bit more.

Check out DocuSign's 
[Embedded Signing REST API Walkthrough](http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning)

Comment: Thank you @andrewwilson for pointing me to the right direction. I tried a small console application in c# (using the .Net Api to docusign) and it seemed to have been working fine till last Friday. I am getting the below error   - "406 - Client browser does not accept the MIME type of the requested page.The page you are looking for cannot be opened by your browser because it has a file name extension that your brows
er does not accept."          
bool result = account.Login(); This call is returning false and when I check the rest error code - I am getting the above message.

Comment: I have edited my original post to add the code snippets! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: thanks once again! That worked! Much appreciated. But I request just one clarification - Like I mentioned in my question,it was working fine with just http all along up until last Friday... it just suddenly started giving out that message this week and stopped working .. is there any explanation to this unpredictable behavior? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not aware of any explanation on why http no longer works, I do know that the documentation always says to use https. So maybe it was working unintentionally before.

Comment: I have edited my question to include the new issues that I encountered. I have the embedded signing all set up - it launched from my site - the document is coming thru, but the tags are not showing up and the document is in free form signing. Please let me know if you have any inputs on this one. Thanks!

Comment: That is another question, please post it as another question. So people can use this question/answer set appropriately and the new question can get the attention it needs.

Comment: I've edited your question back to it's original form. You can see your changes in the history of this to post it as a new question.